Cannot reinstall desktop broken held packages
I followed the instructions to remove pipewire audio because it was not working. The instructions warned that the removal might remove the desktop, and I accepted the risk. The removal did indeed remove the desktop, so I followed the directions to reinstall the desktop, but I keep getting the following error. No matter how many times I tried to reinstall desktop or repair broken packages or unhold these packages, nothing seems to work. I'm getting ready to nuke and reinstall the OS.


Start by making sure you have everything backed up as much as you can. I suspect when the desktop was removed it held on to bits of it you were using? It suggest (to me) you need to somehow completely remove the desktop before re-installing it. Possibly try some of the suggestions here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=985912 (AT OWN RISK).

Thanks I will look into this

try sudo apt pureg gnome*, sudo autoremove, and sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

You have installed non-Ubuntu or wrong-version packages. Those packages are incompatible with your release of Ubuntu, hence the error. The output even provided you a list of clues to get started.

Looks like a source issue to me; which would explain your messages; but few specifics have been provided.  I'd return to basics; ie. sudo apt update & ensure all lines are present, no warnings, no errors & importantly no missing details!  (looking at sources directly can often be easier, unless you regularly scan the output of apt update it can be easy to missing missing details)  Your detail shows only one line of output; less than I'd expect!

Try the following:
Open a terminal.
In it, run:
exec sudo -i
systemctl stop gdm.service
dpkg configure -a
apt update
apt -f install
apt -m install
apt clean
apt autoremove
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

If you get error messages, repeat the commands from dpkg, then reboot with:
reboot

